# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 121835: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, django, utf-8, migration

I am building a Location based Webapp and I am stuck on an Error.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 121835: character maps to

This error is keep showing when i `migrate` the `DataBase`.

models.py

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.PointField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

migrations.py

```
DATA_FILENAME = 'data.json'

def load_data(apps,schema_editor):
    shop = apps.get_model('mains','Shop')
    jsonfile = Path(__file__).parents[2] / DATA_FILENAME

    with open(str(jsonfile)) as datafile:
        objects = json.load(datafile)
        for obj in objects['elements']:
            try:
                objType == obj['type']
                if objType == 'node':
                    tags = obj['tags']
                    name = tags.get('name','no-name')
                    longitide = obj.get('lon',0)
                    latitude = obj.get('lat',0)
                    location = fromstr(f'POINT({longitide} {latitude})', srid=4326)
                    Shop(name=name,location = location).save()

            except KeyError:
                pass

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('mains', '0003_shop'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(load_data)
    ]
```

**Full Error**

```
  Applying mains.0004_auto_20210317_1320...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
  main()
File "manage.py", line 18, in main
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
  utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
  self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
  self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
  output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 85, in wrapped
  res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 243, in handle
  post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
  state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
  state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
  state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
  operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\special.py", line 190, in database_forwards
  self.code(from_state.apps, schema_editor)
File "D:\Development Code\myapp\mains\migrations\0004_auto_20210317_1320.py", line 15, in load_data
  objects = json.load(datafile)
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
  return loads(fp.read(),
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
  return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 121835: character maps to <undefined>
```

**What have i tried**

- I tried many answer like put `encoding='cp437`, it didn't worked for me.
- I also tried `encoding="utf8"`, it didn't work too.

When i add `, encoding = 'cp850'` with `filename` then it shows

> `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

I don't what am i doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error here:

```
shop = apps.get_model('mains','Shop')
```

but later on you continue with:

```
Shop(name=name,location = location).save()
```

and here is a key error (longitUde):

```
location = fromstr(f'POINT({longitide} {latitude})', srid=4326)
```

python is case sensitive. Also please use an online json validator for your file and post the result.

Comment: I am using `Django` and when i do `migrate` then it shows error. How can i migrate it in `NotePad++` ?

Comment: When i change it into `data.json` then it still showing that error .

Comment: Open File in NotePad++, go to encoding, choose `utf-8`, save. But I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here. Are you trying to import back old data after migration? Or are do you get that error when running `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: I am using `load_data` in `Operations` to load the data in database.

Comment: ok ... so this is nor your error. When does it happen?

Comment: When i `migrate` in server.

Comment: I think this would be helpful for you to understand the my concern :- I am following this Toturial :-  https://realpython.com/location-based-app-with-geodjango-tutorial/#creating-a-django-application

Comment: Does my edit help? If so please accept answer, if not please post complete error from console.

Comment: Yes, BUT the error isn't  going. It is still showing

Comment: please insert `print(jsonfile)` below the line `jsonfile = Path ...` and update your question with the output.

Comment: I just did. BUT the same error is showing. It is printing nothing.

Comment: also, is the model already filled with data? Post the code of your `models.py`.

Comment: nothing is printed when you output jsonfile? Post this line from your console: print("----->", jsonfile)

Comment: Updated models.

Comment: When i input `data.json` in console then it opens the correct file

Comment: I thought maybe the path is too long.

Comment: the typo was not the main problem, It could've be noticed by the console. the problem is `charmap`.

Comment: can you somewhere put your whole code online? Github?

Comment: Thanks Dear, It worked. Because the file i was exporting was not in `Json` format. Haha. Well Thanks again for your Help